# The Property Change Event Of Progress Bar Not Firing

Tags: java, swing, exception, swingworker, jprogressbar

I am using JProgressBar for Showing The Progress Of Data Loaded From from DataBase . I am using SwingWorker Class To Load The Data In BackGround Thread using [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)!

The Property Change Event of ProgressBar Of my application is not firing.

Please guide me what i am doing wrong???.

Below is the  SSCCE of the code i am trying to use is as follows.

```
public final class JProgressBarApplication {

    //private static org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker dpDate;
    javax.swing.JPanel pnlDate;
    JLabel label;
    JProgressBar pb;
    boolean taskDone=false;
    LongRunProcess lrpTask;

    public static void main(String... aArgs) {
        JProgressBarApplicationapp = new JProgressBarApplication();
        app.buildAndDisplayGui();
    }

    // PRIVATE //
    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        buildContent(frame);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class showDialog implements ActionListener {

        /**
        * Defining the dialog's owner JFrame is highly recommended.
        */
        showDialog(JFrame aFrame) {    
            Date serverDate = null;
            fFrame = aFrame;    

        }

        public void GetData() {    
        // Code To Get Data From DB    
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvent) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fFrame, "This is a dialog");
        }
        private JFrame fFrame;
    }

    private void buildContent(JFrame aFrame) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));

        JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(new MinimalSwingApplication.showDialog(aFrame));
        panel.add(ok);

        pb = new JProgressBar(0, 20);
        pb.setValue(0);
        pb.setStringPainted(true);
        aFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });
        pb.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                pbPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });         

        aFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        aFrame.getContentPane().add(pb);
        aFrame.getContentPane().add(label);
    }

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

        // TODO add your handling code here:
        lrpTask = new LongRunProcess(this, "1", 0);
        taskDone =false;
        lrpTask.execute();
        lrpTask.addPropertyChangeListener(pb.getPropertyChangeListeners()[0]);
    }

    private void pbPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (!taskDone) {
            if (lrpTask !=null) {
                int progress = lrpTask.getProgress();
                pb.setValue(progress);
                String str = "<html>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "<b>" + 
                String.format( "Completed %d%% of task.\n", progress) + "</b>" + "</font>" + "</html>";
                if (lrpTask.getProgress()==100) {
                    done() ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void done() {
        //Tell progress listener to stop updating progress bar.
        taskDone = true;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        pb.setValue(pb.getMinimum());
        String str = "<html>" + "<font color=\"#FF0000\">" + "<b>" + " Form Loading completed." + "</b>" + "</font>" + "</html>";
        label.setText(str);
    }      
}

class LongRunProcess extends SwingWorker {
    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    MinimalSwingApplication frm;
    String mID=null;
    int rowNo=0 ;
    LongRunProcess(MinimalSwingApplication jframe,String mID_,int rowNo_) {
        frm =jframe;
        mID=mID_;
        rowNo=rowNo_ ;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Integer result = 0;               

        try {                        
            frm.GetData();                       
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Edit: with @mKorbel answer**

I use the following function

```
 private void getLongRunningTask(String id_ ,int row_){
  final String id=id_;
  final int row=row_;
    Thread process=  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
      GetData(id,row);
      }
  });
  process.start();
```

}

Instead Of using SwingWorker object Before.

```
  lrpTask = new LongRunProcess(this, "1", 0);
  taskDone =false;
  lrpTask.execute();
```

Get The following Exceptions

```
    debug:
    /JewelleryERPApplication/build/classes/java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 >= 8
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at Utilities.Utility.ChangeJTableColumnSize(Utility.java:304)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.RefreshReplicateDetailJTable(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:2850)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetDetailData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:496)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:638)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(SwingUtilities2.java:1841)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2585)
at javax.swing.JTable.getColumnClass(JTable.java:2701)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI$SynthTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(SynthTableUI.java:790)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5735)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
at                        javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paint(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:648)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableHeaderUI.paint(SynthTableHeaderUI.java:173)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableHeaderUI.update(SynthTableHeaderUI.java:144)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
at  javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    Exception in thread "Thread-44" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:554)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.removeColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:151)
at javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(JTable.java:1286)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4389)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3691)
at  jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetDetailData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:582)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:642)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumnIndex(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:282)
at javax.swing.JTable.getColumn(JTable.java:2564)
at Utilities.Utility.AddingExtraColumnsAndComboForViews(Utility.java:2513)
at Utilities.Utility.RefreshReplicatedDataAndHeader(Utility.java:2307)
at  jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.RefreshReplicateDetailJTable(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:2804)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetDetailData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:496)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:638)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Exception in thread "Thread-49" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "E2856D+RWN"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at  jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.CalcWeight(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:774)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:652)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:577)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:725)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    Exception in thread "Thread-50" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "E2856D+RWN"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.CalcWeight(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:774)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:652)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 >= 4
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:577)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
at  javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    Exception in thread "Thread-56" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:554)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.removeColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:151)
at javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(JTable.java:1286)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4389)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3691)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetDetailData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:582)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:642)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3323)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Edit For Code Generating Exceptions**

**Sample Exception1**

```
    .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:554)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.removeColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:151)
at javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(JTable.java:1286)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4389)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3691)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetDetailData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:493)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.GetData(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:638)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler$13.run(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:3380)
```

**Code At Which Exception occured**

```
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data_RcvGoodsFromFilerDt, header_RcvGoodsFromFilerDt);

     tblDetailInfo.setModel(dtm);
```

**Sample Exception 2**

```
   Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12.950"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.RcvGoodsFromFiler.CalcWeight(RcvGoodsFromFiler.java:774)
```

**Code At Which Exception occured**

```
   qt += Integer.parseInt( tblDetailInfo.getValueAt(r, 8).toString() );

    Some Exceptions occured at unknown Code Point

    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? For what it's worth, your code above doesn't comply with the SSCCE standard since it requires at least one non-core Java class and has much code unrelated to the main problem, the latter making it more difficult to see and understand your main problem. Also, I don't see any background threading or use of a SwingWorker just yet.

Comment: Actually the progress bar starts when my Data is being loaded not fiulfilling my requirement.

Comment: I want that the  Progress Bar works in parallel to the getData() function what shall i do for that

Comment: I remove un related code now

Comment: Again, are you using a SwingWorker to load the data in a background thread?

Comment: No i am not  using SwingWorker

Comment: Then that's likely the solution that you are looking for. If you desire concurrency and also desire to not freeze your GUI, then you *must* use background threading. A SwingWorker simplifies this and also ties  in nicely with JProgressBars. Please check out the tutorials that show just this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20025/discussion-between-syed-muhammad-mubashir-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Comment: You never set any progress in your `SwingWorker`. Use the `setProgress` method and it will fire events

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir Take a look at the code in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525171/swing-parent-jframe-jpanel-unusable-clickable-while-child-panel-is-loaded/13525448#13525448 . The problem is that your are not publishing any intermediate result.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code to make it at least readable (following _java_ naming conventions might help its readability as well ;-) - and don't forget to make it an SSCCE, as mentioned already!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JProgressBar update from SwingWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773552/jprogressbar-update-from-swingworker)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet how can i use your example as you have used SwingWorker<void,Integer> example also the process takes List<Integer> as param which is not in my case.

Comment: @Robin can you tell how can i use the loop you used to simulate long running task if my Long Running Task is DB select transaction. as used in your [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565)!

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir Read the Javadoc of SwingWorker. The method `process` is typed `process(List<V> chunks) ` where `V` is the first type argument of `SwingWorker`. Although you can use that type and the `process` method to indicate the current progress of your work, you can also use `setProgress` and attach a PropertyChangelistener to the property 'progress' of the SwingWorker to update the UI. The important thing is to ensure that your "task" is reporting intermediate progress.

Comment: See my latest edit on question using Runnable Thread and i am getting bunch of exceptions as he mentioned in his answer that Runnable is better than SwingWorker

Answer (score 3):

- You can implement `Runnable`; it avoids `Future` and generics, but it is easy to get wrong.
- This answer [compares `SwingWorker` and `Runnable` for similar action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774277/714968); `SwingWorker` has the advantage, but it requires better knowledge about `Java Essential Classes`.
- `SwingWorker` is proper way and is designated for single long running thread; for multithreading, invoke `SwingWorker` from `Executor`.
- [Example about `SwingWorker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113944/how-cancel-the-execution-of-a-swingworker/6114890#6114890).
- [Example about `get()` exceptions from `SwingWorker` and `PropertyChangeListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa).

Comment: +1 I was struck by the second bullet, but it's just a flesh wound. :-)

Comment: "This answer compares SwingWorker and Runnable for similar action"  with this example i can not understand how to use this example as u hhave used the wait method , and i am using Slow DataBase Transactions. By use of SwingWorker the speed of my application has been dramatically improved but is generating exceptins in some cases @mKorbel

Comment: @mKorbel please see the exceptions i edited my question by the runnable.

Comment: all arrays starting with zero (0 :-), debug that because you put 9 elements to the 8.th model, better could be to edit your question with code generated this issue

Comment: @mKorbel Question has been edited with code generating the exceptions.

Comment: (I think) never to change model from models event, did you able 1) never to parse objects from JTable or its model change column to Double, [testing by add TableModelListener, use System.out.println()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099098/why-never-change-the-notifier-in-receiving-a-change-event)

Comment: be sure that exceptions this type are only about funny/crazy typos in code, sure I made that 1Mio times,

Comment: and they are coming only some times. When i refresh my form more frequently.

Comment: ???? whaaaats :-) :-) `When i refresh my form more frequently.` then there must be Concurency issue, have to debug and properly timing code from/to, sure in most cases is better to wrote a new code and to forgot about old

Comment: @mKorbel can you please tell how to update the model if i load the  latest data from Database .

Comment: @mKorbel can you tell how to handle concurrency in my case.

Comment: no idea, but you can to start with [great code by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/)

Comment: I tried process.sleep(10) and that works for me. Thanks for your valueable guidance.

Comment: note, process.sleep(10) is under latency proper value is over 15-21 for Windows platform,

Comment: which is the best value for 17,18,19,20 or 21

Comment: I tried 20 and now all the exceptions have been eliminated now thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

@mKorbel has [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540314/230513) many instructive examples, but the key is invoking `setProgress()` from the worker's `doInBackground()`. `SwingWorker` handles the required synchronization. Several helpful answers expand on the topic in this related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10773552/230513), including a reference to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Comment: the example u show is using Thread.Sleep() to show Slow Process in doInBackGound method of SwingWorker but i am using simply long running DataBase transaction in which time taken is unknown to me. Can you tell how to cater this problem. @trashgod

Comment: This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata) shows `executeQuery()`. It also adds a little `Thread.sleep()` to simulate latency.

Comment: you showed the above example is doing the same thing and it implements the same logic on the loop of the result set . In my case i don't know  the time of the  completion of my query as it is the result of some heavy stored proc execution. @trashgod

Comment: your's and this example uses the SwingWorker<List<Double>, Double> as i am using Simple SwingWorker()

Comment: in my case  frm.GetData() is the result of the the execution of many sps and updating many table models in my form.

Comment: How can i use your      for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                x = x - (((x * x - 2) / (2 * x)));
                setProgress(i * (100 / N));
                publish(Double.valueOf(x)); 
                Thread.sleep(1000); // simulate latency
            }
            return Double.valueOf(x); as  instead of Thread.sleep(1000)  frm.GetData()  in my case contains lots of Stored procs execution with un-known time.

Comment: That's mean i can not use looping

Comment: Yes, the examples are contrived to show percent complete. You could query a row count at the beginning of your loop, and use that in the denominator of `setProgres()`.